# SQL Server Compact toolbox diff script doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-toolbox

I have two `.sdf` files and I tried run "Script Database diff" on "SQL Server Compact toolbox for runtime 4.0" to get differences between this two files, I got this as result:

```
-- This database diff script contains the following objects:
-- - Tables:  Any that are not in the destination
-- -          (tables that are only in the destination are not dropped)
-- - Columns: Any added, deleted, changed columns for existing tables
-- - Indexes: Any added, deleted indexes for existing tables
-- - Foreign keys: Any added, deleted foreign keys for existing tables
-- ** Make sure to test against a production version of the destination database! ** 

-- Script Date: 30.01.2023 09:37  - ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting version 3.5.2.90
```

and nothing happens. My database files are changed, but the differences are not displayed in the database.

I tried to use ExportSQLCe40 with diff param, but then I got a lot "Alter table" lines and nothing more.

Is there any option to get differences between two `.sdf` database files?

Comment: As a side qusetion, have you considered switching off of compact edition? It was discontinued back in 2013, and support ended entirely for it in 2021.

Comment: Please report an issue in the Github repo and I will have a look